# Scanning dynamodb with optional parameters

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Im new with dynamodb and Im trying to make a function to scan a table and have an optional parameter but Im not quite sure how to implement it. This is the code I have so far:

```
def scan_table(table, store=None, dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression=Key('store').eq(store),
            ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'],
            ProjectionExpression="UID, #name, description",
            ExpressionAttributeNames={'#name': 'name'}
        )
        data.extend(response['Items'])
    return data
```

So ideally what I'd want to happen is if I pass in a store for example `"walmart"` I only get products from walmart. However If I dont pass anything I would get ALL products in the entire table. How can I do that in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Attribute` instead of `Key` in your filter expression.

`FilterExpression (condition from boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr method) -- The condition(s) an attribute(s) must meet. Valid conditions are listed in the DynamoDB Reference Guide.`

Please refer this documentation for more information:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan

Also, I would suggest you to create an GSI for `store` column since that you would be querying against it whenever needed (I supposed). Therefore, it could save you more in terms of RCU cost and not affecting the overall performance on your table.